# Update function REST with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

Learning alot on how to use REST, currently I am able to create and delete items but can't get the update function to work. I tried so many combinations  but keep getting 400 bad requests errors stating that the `data.d.__metadata.etag` is invalid.

THis is the code thats causing the the trouble:

```
// Saves a incident. If there is no value in the #Incident_ID hidden field then
// a new incident is created by "POST" request. Otherwise an existing incident
// is updated with "PUT" request.
saveIncident: function (data) {
    var requestType = $('#Incident_ID').val() != '' ? 'PUT' : 'POST';
    var CREATE_Headers = {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"};
    var UPDATE_Headers = {"accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose","X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE","If-Match" : "data.d.__metadata.etag"};
    var headertype = $('#Incident_ID').val() != '' ? UPDATE_Headers : CREATE_Headers;

    $.ajax({
        url: data.d.__metadata.etag,
        type: requestType,
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: headertype,
        data: JSON.stringify(IncidentManager.collectFieldValues()),
        success: function (data) {
        console.log("These are the resulsts "+data.d);
        }
    });
},
```

I put in the URL manually but still getting the same issue. I changed the IF-Match header to `W/"3"` then I start getting errors saying `3` is not valid header value. I changed the header to `"If-Match" : "data.d.__metadata.type"`then I start getting errors saying `d` is not a valid header value. Not quite sure what is it im missing here.

I searched several examples to base myself from such as:
http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/03/22/list-items-manipulation-via-rest-api-in-sharepoint-2010/ 
http://binduchinnasamy.blogspot.ca/2012/07/create-update-delete-and-read.html
https://codeontime.com/print/learn/rest/jquery/crud-create-read-update-delete

I tried several different combinations but not able to get this to work. Below is my javascript code. Any advice would be appreciated, im running out of hair to pull.

```
var IncidentManager = {
    // Returns the url of the application server of a demo web app.
    basePath: function () { return '../../../../_vti_bin/listData.svc'; },

    // Formats a URI of a product
    createIncidentUrl: function (requestType) {
        if (requestType == 'POST')
            return this.basePath() + '/GDI_PROD_Incidents';
        return this.basePath() + '/GDI_PROD_Incidents('+ encodeURIComponent($('#Incident_ID').val())+')';
    },  
    // Creates an object with the properties retrievd from the input fields 
    // of the "ProductDetails" form.
    collectFieldValues: function () {
        return {
            Description: $('#Description').val(),
            Incident: $('#Incident').val(),
            ÉtatValue: $('#état').val(),
            PrioritéValue: $('#Priorité').val(),
            Duré: $('#Duré').val(),
            Date_de_début:  $('#DateDeDébut').val(),
            Date_de_fin:  $('#DateDeFin').val(),
            Autres_Groupe_Support_Prime: $('#Autres_Groupe_Support_Prime').val(),
            ResponsableValue: $('#Prime').val(),
            Impact: $('#Impact').val(),
            Temps_Consacré: $('#Temps_Consacré').val(),
            Type_de_tempsValue: $('#Type_de_temps').val(),
            Journal_des_actions: $('#Journal_des_actions').val(),
            Dépanage: $('#Dépannage_effectué').val(),
            Suivi: $('#Suivi').val(),
            Ressources: $('#Ressources').val()
        };
    },
    // Saves a incident. If there is no value in the #Incident_ID hidden field then
    // a new incident is created by "POST" request. Otherwise an existing incident
    // is updated with "PUT" request.
    saveIncident: function (data) {
        var requestType = $('#Incident_ID').val() != '' ? 'PUT' : 'POST';
        var CREATE_Headers = {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"};
        var UPDATE_Headers = {"accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose","X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE","If-Match" : "data.d.__metadata.etag"};
        var headertype = $('#Incident_ID').val() != '' ? UPDATE_Headers : CREATE_Headers;

        $.ajax({
            url: data.d.__metadata.etag,
            type: requestType,
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: headertype,
            data: JSON.stringify(IncidentManager.collectFieldValues()),
            success: function (data) {
            console.log("These are the resulsts "+data.d);
            }
        });
    },
};
```

Comment: I think that it should be `"If-Match" : data.d._metadata.etag`  without the quotes

Comment: Thats gives me `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'd' of undefined` :(

Comment: It means  that data does not have `d` as a known property. can you debug and check what properties does `data` have.

Comment: Whats the best way to debug this?

Comment: `console.log(data)` and check the browser console window.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! After alot of research I found 2 blogs which explained alot about ETAG and made it clearer for me on how to use my if-match statement.

http://blogs.msdn.com/astoriateam/archive/2008/04/22/optimistic-concurrency-data-services.aspx.

http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/03/22/list-items-manipulation-via-rest-api-in-sharepoint-2010/

```
When updating or deleting items within SharePoint lists via REST you must specify the Entity Tag (eTag) value that was returned with the item during the initial query. This enables SharePoint to determine if the item has changed since it was requested. Alternatively you can tell SharePoint to perform the operation regardless by specifying * as the eTag value. For example:

“If-Match”: item.__metadata.etag can be used to specify the actual eTag value (‘item’ is the object returned from SharePoint containing the list item in JSON format).
“If-Match”: “*” can be used to match any eTag value resulting in the operation being performed regardless of the actual value.
```

I ended up using the special value "*" so that it would allow any value to match. So I changed my code from:

```
var UPDATE_Headers = {"accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose","X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE","If-Match" : "data.d.__metadata.etag"};
```

to this:

```
var UPDATE_Headers = {"accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose","X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE","If-Match" : "*"};
```

Next I started getting errors again with my header but specifically with "X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE". The error stated that I could not use the X-HTTP-Method with PUT and had to be sent as POST. Found another blog to explain more on how to use it properly here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx

```
- A PUT request is used to update an entire entity. If no values are specified for fields in the entity, the fields will be set to default values.

- A MERGE request is used to update only those field values that have changed. Any fields that are not specified by the operation will remain set to their current value.
```

Now here is the updated code that now works for me:

```
var IncidentManager = {
    // Returns the url of the application server of a demo web app.
    basePath: function () { return '../../../../_vti_bin/listData.svc'; },

    // Creates an object with the properties retrievd from the input fields 
    // of the "ProductDetails" form.
    collectFieldValues: function () {
        return {
            Description: $('#Description').val(),
            Incident: $('#Incident').val(),
            ÉtatValue: $('#état').val(),
            PrioritéValue: $('#Priorité').val(),
            Duré: $('#Duré').val(),
            Date_de_début:  $('#DateDeDébut').val(),
            Date_de_fin:  $('#DateDeFin').val(),
            Autres_Groupe_Support_Prime: $('#Autres_Groupe_Support_Prime').val(),
            ResponsableValue: $('#Prime').val(),
            Impact: $('#Impact').val(),
            Temps_Consacré: $('#Temps_Consacré').val(),
            Type_de_tempsValue: $('#Type_de_temps').val(),
            Journal_des_actions: $('#Journal_des_actions').val(),
            Dépanage: $('#Dépannage_effectué').val(),
            Suivi: $('#Suivi').val(),
            Ressources: $('#Ressources').val()
        };
    },
    // Saves a incident. If there is no value in the #Incident_ID hidden field then
    // a new incident is created by "POST" request. Otherwise an existing incident
    // is updated with "PUT" request.
    saveIncident: function (data) {

        var New_Incident_URL = this.basePath() + '/GDI_PROD_Incidents';
        var UPDATE_Incident_URL = this.basePath() + '/GDI_PROD_Incidents('+ encodeURIComponent($('#Incident_ID').val())+')';
        var createIncidentUrl = $('#Incident_ID').val() != '' ? UPDATE_Incident_URL : New_Incident_URL;

        var CREATE_Headers = {"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"};
        var UPDATE_Headers = {"accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose","X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE","If-Match":"*"};
        var headertype = $('#Incident_ID').val() != '' ? UPDATE_Headers : CREATE_Headers;

        $.ajax({
            url: createIncidentUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: headertype,
            data: JSON.stringify(IncidentManager.collectFieldValues()),
            success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            }
        });
    },
};
```